# If $A \subseteq B$, $a \in A$ and $a \not\in B \setminus C$, then $a\in C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is the question:

> Suppose that $A \subseteq B$, $a \in A$ and $a \not\in B \setminus C$. Prove by the method of contradiction that
>   a ∈ C.

This is my proof:

Suppose by contradiction $a \not\in C$

$A \subseteq B$ means that $\forall x (x \in A \rightarrow x \in B)$

We know that $a \in A$ and $a \not\in B \setminus C$, which means that $a \in A \land (a \not\in B \lor a \in C)$

Since we know that all elements of $A$ belong also to $B$, we know that if $a \in A$, then $a \in B$, therefore $a \not\in B$ is false, then $a \in C$ must be true.

Therefore $a \not\in C$ is a contradiction.

Comment: Looks good. I personally always convert $x \in S \setminus T$ to $x \in S \land \neg x \in T$, but you can do whatever works for you.

Comment: Remove 'suppose $a\not\in C$' and 'therefore contradiction' and the proof is still correct.. The contradiction steps are really unnecessary here, but it's correct.

Comment: @mathh: looks like the assignment was to use a proof by contradiction specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on hypothese $a\notin C$ you proved that $a\in C$ and this statement contradicts the hypothese. In that sense it is indeed a proof by contradiction.

In fact you gave a proof of: $$a\notin C\Rightarrow a\in C$$ wich is equivalent with each of the following statements:

- $\neg a\notin C\vee a\in C$
- $a\in C\vee a\in C$
- $a\in C$

It is not correct to say "therefore $a\notin C$ is a contradiction". It should be something like "$a\notin C$ implies $a\in C$ and a contradiction is found."